# Is calling a stable function performance comparable to reading values from a table?

Tags: postgresql, performance, functions, materialized-view

Let's say we have a function `_test_has_group_feature`, which is meant to check if a group (identified by a name) has a particular feature (identified by name).

```sql
_test_has_group_feature(group_name, feature_name)
```

For the purpose of this example, let's say that there aren't many unique group names (10) and there aren't many unique features (10), i.e. the permutations are limited.

In our schema, such function can be implemented as such:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _test_has_group_feature (_user_group_nid text, _user_feature_nid text)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
  SELECT coalesce(bool_and(ufug1.granted), false)
  FROM user_group ug1
  INNER JOIN user_feature_user_group ufug1 ON
    ufug1.user_group_id = ug1.id
  INNER JOIN user_feature uf1 ON
    uf1.id = ufug1.user_feature_id
  WHERE
    ug1.nid = _user_group_nid AND
    uf1.nid = _user_feature_nid
$$
LANGUAGE sql
STABLE
PARALLEL SAFE;
```

However, because the permutations are finite, we could also create a materialized view that makes the same data easy to access. Something like this:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW _test_user_group_feature_granted AS
SELECT ug1.nid user_group_nid, uf1.nid user_feature_nid, coalesce(bool_and(ufug1.granted), false)
FROM user_group ug1
INNER JOIN user_feature_user_group ufug1 ON
  ufug1.user_group_id = ug1.id
INNER JOIN user_feature uf1 ON
  uf1.id = ufug1.user_feature_id
GROUP BY 1, 2;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON _test_user_group_feature_granted (
  user_group_nid,
  user_feature_nid
);
```

Finally... is there a performance difference between invoking the stable function or joining the materialized table?, i.e.

```sql
SELECT
  ug1.nid,
  _test_has_group_feature(ug1.nid, 'MANAGE_JOB_POSTINGS'::text)
FROM user_group ug1
```

VS

```sql
SELECT
  ug1.nid,
  t1.granted
FROM user_group ug1
INNER JOIN _test_user_group_feature_granted t1
ON t1.user_group_nid = ug1.nid
```

How would this difference change if we joined `user_account` table, i.e. more records would be fetched, but the number of permutations invoking `_test_has_group_feature` would not change?

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: I already know the answer, but I'd like to understand why that is the case. Logically, I would expect that the nature of stable function here would allow for a more effective cache map.